# Angular prod build выдаёт ERROR in Cannot assign to a reference or variable!

Tags: typescript, angular, npm, angular-cli

Не удаётся собрать `prod` версию приложения на [angular](/questions/tagged/angular).

IDE в консоли выдаёт только такое сообщение:

> ERROR in Cannot assign to a reference or variable!

Эту проблему я могу решить только добавив такие опции к команде сборки:

```
--aot=false --buildOptimizer=false
```

Однако, даже с этими опциями приложение падает после деплоя уже в браузере с такой ошибкой:

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'init' of undefined

Это может быть [исправлено](https://github.com/angular/flex-layout/issues/950) добавлением ещё одной опции:

```
--optimization=false
```

В итоге я могу развернуть только девелоперскую версию приложения, без оптимизаций и прочего.

---

Когда я пробую собрать приложение вот этой командой:

```
npm run ng build -- --prod
```

я получаю вот такой лог:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ 'C:\\Backend\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Users\\USER_NAME\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'run',
1 verbose cli   'ng',
1 verbose cli   'build',
1 verbose cli   '--',
1 verbose cli   '--prod' ]
2 info using npm@6.10.2
3 info using node@v10.15.3
4 verbose run-script [ 'preng', 'ng', 'postng' ]
5 info lifecycle dont-play-with-gp-web@0.0.2~preng: dont-play-with-gp-web@0.0.2
6 info lifecycle dont-play-with-gp-web@0.0.2~ng: dont-play-with-gp-web@0.0.2
7 verbose lifecycle dont-play-with-gp-web@0.0.2~ng: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle dont-play-with-gp-web@0.0.2~ng: PATH: C:\Users\USER_NAME\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin;C:\DEV\WebStormProjects\dont-play-with-gp-web\node_modules\.bin;C:\DEV\WebStormProjects\dont-play-with-gp-web\node_modules\.bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Backend\IntelliJ IDEA 2018.3.5\jre64;C:\Backend\PostgreSQL\10\bin;C:\Backend\nodejs;C:\Backend\WinSCP\;C:\Android\sdk\platform-tools;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Users\USER_NAME\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;
9 verbose lifecycle dont-play-with-gp-web@0.0.2~ng: CWD: C:\DEV\WebStormProjects\dont-play-with-gp-web
10 silly lifecycle dont-play-with-gp-web@0.0.2~ng: Args: [ '/d /s /c', 'ng "build" "--prod"' ]
11 silly lifecycle dont-play-with-gp-web@0.0.2~ng: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle dont-play-with-gp-web@0.0.2~ng: Failed to exec ng script
13 verbose stack Error: dont-play-with-gp-web@0.0.2 ng: `ng "build" "--prod"`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Users\USER_NAME\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\index.js:326:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:189:13)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Users\USER_NAME\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\lib\spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:189:13)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:970:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:259:5)
14 verbose pkgid dont-play-with-gp-web@0.0.2
15 verbose cwd C:\DEV\WebStormProjects\dont-play-with-gp-web
16 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.17134
17 verbose argv "C:\\Backend\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\USER_NAME\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "ng" "build" "--" "--prod"
18 verbose node v10.15.3
19 verbose npm  v6.10.2
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error dont-play-with-gp-web@0.0.2 ng: `ng "build" "--prod"`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the dont-play-with-gp-web@0.0.2 ng script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Я пытался обновить все зависимости, но это не помогло.

Результат вызова `ng version`:

```
Angular CLI: 8.3.4
Node: 10.15.3
OS: win32 x64
Angular: 8.2.6
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... language-service, platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic
... router

Package                           Version
-----------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect         0.803.4
@angular-devkit/build-angular     0.803.4
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.803.4
@angular-devkit/build-webpack     0.803.4
@angular-devkit/core              8.3.4
@angular-devkit/schematics        8.3.4
@angular/cdk                      8.2.0
@angular/cli                      8.3.4
@angular/flex-layout              8.0.0-beta.27
@angular/material                 8.2.0
@ngtools/webpack                  8.3.4
@schematics/angular               8.3.4
@schematics/update                0.803.4
rxjs                              6.5.3
typescript                        3.5.3
webpack                           4.39.2
```

И `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "dont-play-with-gp-web",
  "version": "0.0.2",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^8.2.6",
    "@angular/cdk": "^8.2.0",
    "@angular/common": "~8.2.6",
    "@angular/compiler": "~8.2.6",
    "@angular/core": "~8.2.6",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "8.0.0-beta.27",
    "@angular/forms": "~8.2.6",
    "@angular/material": "^8.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~8.2.6",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~8.2.6",
    "@angular/router": "~8.2.6",
    "angular-markdown-editor": "^2.0.2",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "jquery": "^3.4.1",
    "ngx-infinite-scroll": "^8.0.0",
    "ngx-markdown": "^8.1.0",
    "ngx-material-file-input": "^2.0.0",
    "rxjs": "~6.5.3",
    "tslib": "^1.9.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.9.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.803.4",
    "@angular/cli": "~8.3.4",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~8.2.6",
    "@angular/language-service": "~8.2.6",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.4.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/jquery": "^3.3.31",
    "@types/node": "~12.7.5",
    "codelyzer": "^5.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.4.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~4.3.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.0",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~8.4.1",
    "tslint": "~5.20.0",
    "typescript": "^3.5.3"
  }
}
```

Что делать в таком случае? Как найти причину ошибки и как её исправить?

Если это поможет - вот исходники:

https://bitbucket.org/mohaxspb/gp-web/commits/tag/ATTEMPT_TO_FIX_PROD_BUILD_WITH_DEPS_UPDATE

---

Этот же вопрос на английском: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57978475/angular-prod-build-error-in-cannot-assign-to-a-reference-or-variable

**UPD:**
Таки нашёл способ использовать мою директиву без ломания PROD билда. Однако для этого требуется править исходник компилятора [тут](https://github.com/angular/compiler-builds/blob/6eaf2806247d295da17de900d66059932f23923a/src/compiler_util/expression_converter.js#L489)

Там идёт проверка типа выражения в шаблоне `if (localExpr instanceof ReadPropExpr)` и, если добавить ещё одно условие `|| localExpr instanceof ReadVarExpr)` всё работает (PROD билд, деплой и запуск в браузере). Также есть возможность улучшить отображаемую [ошибку](https://github.com/angular/compiler-builds/blob/6eaf2806247d295da17de900d66059932f23923a/src/compiler_util/expression_converter.js#L500) добавив `JSON.stringify(ast)` в сообщение оной.

Comment: привет. А есть ли предпосылки для этой ошибки? возможно ты перевел существующее приложение на новую версию? и возможно ли у себя локально это развернуть чтоб увидеть ошибку?

Comment: @overthesanity, привет) Приложение свежее, это первый раз когда я пытался `prod` билд сделать. Сейчас я из отчаяния пошёл по пути удаления частей приложения для того, чтобы найти проблемное место. После удаления вообще всех компонентов кроме главного сборка работает. Теперь буду добавлять по одному компоненту и смотреть когда сломается. По последнему вопросу не очень понял. Имеется в виду могу ли я не на сереве, а на ноуте установить web-server и на нём запустить? Если да, то не очень понимаю как мне это поможет) Если же вопрос про исходники - то ссылка в конце вопроса есть)

Comment: я битбакетом не умею пользоваться, и да, я имел в виду исходники. Там просто коммиты открываются. Попробую к себе склонить и поднять

Comment: @overthesanity, спасибо большое за попытку помочь! =)

Comment: у меня получилось сбилдить в продакшн моде. Я залез в компилятор в AST парсер и нашел где кидается эксепшн `Cannot assign to a reference or variable!`. У тебя в файле `feed.component.html` есть выражение `(change)="translation = getTranslationForLanguageFromArticle($event.value, article)"` - вот его парсер и не может понять

Comment: потом еще была ошибка `Property 'loadArticles' is private and only accessible within class 'FeedComponent'`, но там достаточно убрать `private` и если запустить `ng build --prod`, то все ок

Comment: @overthesanity, да, это оно! Спасибо! Можете в ответе написать подробности `залез в компилятор в AST парсер и нашел где кидается эксепшн Cannot assign to a reference or variable!`? Чтобы в следующий раз знать что делать? =)

Comment: это просто хардкорный подход :DD сама ошибка просто не self-descriptive так сказать и не говорит о том ГДЕ именно кидается эксепшн )) но ответ могу оставить, так уж и быть)

Comment: Таки да, в этом то и проблема - не написано куда смотреть( И есть ли у вас предложения как можно заменить проблемное место? Типа менять значение переменной из шаблона по событию?

Comment: да, лучше просто метод создай типа `(change)="changeTranslation($event.value, article)"` и в самом методе компонента `this.translation = this.getTranslationForLanguageFromArticle(...)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вообще, так сложилось, что эксепшены от AST парсера это головная боль, потому что они не несут в себе ничего полезного, кроме просто сообщения:

> ERROR in Cannot assign to a reference or variable!

(здесь нужна фотка плачущего Тоби Магуайра из фильма Человек паук )

Компоновщик, например, всегда пишет то место, в котором он не может объединить выражения шаблона, поэтому с ним намного легче.

Один из вариантов решения проблемы это конечно же попытаться погуглить, но весь круг замкнется на том, что все будут предлагать проверить директиву `ngModel`.

---

Второй вариант, более хардкорный. Стоит залезть в сам компилятор и чуть-чуть подебажить. Angular использует `node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js` во время билда так как нода понимает только CommonJS (не поднимаем тему ESM).

Далее делаем поиск по тексту `Cannot assign to a reference or variable!` и находим класс `_AstToIrVisitor` и метод `visitPropertyWrite`. Видим строчку:

```
// Otherwise it's an error.
throw new Error('Cannot assign to a reference or variable!');
```

Убеждаемся, что это фиаско, эксепшн кидается вообще без какой-либо информации

Тогда делаем проще, перед эксепшеном добавляем `console.log(ast)`, где `ast` это параметр функции `visitPropertyWrite`, после этого парсер выдаст нам в консоль инстанс класса `PropertyWrite`:

```
PropertyWrite {
  span: ParseSpan { start: 0, end: 73 },
  receiver: ImplicitReceiver { span: ParseSpan { start: 0, end: 0 } },
  name: 'translation',
  value: MethodCall {
    span: ParseSpan { start: 14, end: 73 },
    receiver: ImplicitReceiver { span: [ParseSpan] },
    name: 'getTranslationForLanguageFromArticle',
    args: [ [PropertyRead], [PropertyRead] ]
  }
}
```

Понимаем, что нам нужно выяснить связь между свойством `translation` и вызовом метода `getTranslationForLanguageFromArticle`. После поиска в IDE находим строчку в `feed.component.html`:

```
(change)="translation = getTranslationForLanguageFromArticle($event.value, article)"
```

Вот ее то парсер и не может понять.

Лучше всего просто создать метод в компоненте `changeTranslation` и в нем изменять свойство `translation`:

```
this.translation = getTranslationForLanguageFromArticle(value, article);
```

Ну и в шаблоне сделать замену:

```
(change)="changeTranslation($event.value, article)"
```

Comment: Спасибо, вы меня спасли) Правда, в шаблоне так просто не получится сделать - у меня там `translation` - это переменная, объявленная прямо в шаблоне через самописную директиву и в `ts` файл её, вроде, не вынести. Буду думать как это дело переписать)

Comment: А можете ещё немного деталей по поводу дебага компилятора написать? Хочу сам попробовать аналогичный результат получить, но не очень понятно что и как запускать надо)

Comment: И хотите ли вы этот же ответ на en-SO написать? Если нет - я тогда сам, со ссылкой на вас могу. Негоже вопрос без ответа оставлять)

Comment: а, я только щас увидел что `translation` - локальная переменная, попробуй менять тогда `article.translations[indexOfCorrectArticleTranslation(article)]`, ну по крайней мере ты знаешь куда двигаться. По поводу компилятора - просто редактируешь файл, путь к нему я указал, добавляешь туда консоль логи и прочее, что угодно в общем, после этого `ng build` пишешь и увидишь свои логи.

Comment: добавлю ответ на en-SO

Comment: Ого, круто! =) Всё время удивляюсь как всё просто в фронтенде))) По поводу переменной буду думать... Наверное просто в ts файле массив с индексами объявлю. Предложенный способ только один раз срабатывает(

Comment:  почти все просто )) вопрос становится боком когда доходит до перфоманса на энтерпрайзе, вот там сидишь с синим лицом и где-то мелькает мысль в голове - а может я в Go пойду? )))

Comment: Блин, надеюсь у меня такого никогда не будет))) "Работает - и ладно" - вот мой девиз)))