# не могу запустить рабочий каркас спринг(boot или jetty)-mvc-hibernate(mysql)-webppa

Tags: java, mvc, spring-mvc, spring-boot

1. первая попытка ... неудачно ... хоть удаляй короче, 
   https://github.com/stanislavgr79/core.git

idea-мавен-спринг-boot

если кто может скажите что нет так. я уже задолбался - делаю все по видео - а не работает

в конфиге спринга - не воспринимает вообще никак

2. попытка (репа ниже) также неудачна настолько - что можно тоже все удалять и начинать с нуля, скорее всего
   UserRepository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
   хотя я все делал посекундно с видео ютуба - но  у меня не работает
   бут jetty

   ## https://github.com/stanislavgr79/epam.git

можете закидать мой вопрос минусами - после суток за компом мне на рейтинг пофиг, пока не сделаю спать не пойду - начинаю 3-ю попытку, с другого видео

```
<mvc:annotation-driven/>
<context:component-scan base-package="org.epam.stanislavgr79"/>

<bean name="jackson2ObjectMapper" class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.Jackson2ObjectMapperFactoryBean">
    <property name="indentOutput" value="true"/>
</bean>

<mvc:annotation-driven>
    <mvc:message-converters>
        <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter">
            <property name="objectMapper" ref="jackson2ObjectMapper" />
        </bean>
    </mvc:message-converters>
</mvc:annotation-driven>


<mvc:view-controller path="/" view-name="users_page"/>

<bean id="resolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/pages/"/>
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
</bean>
```

вот это users_page  подчеркивает красным

Comment: Дам вам небольшую подсказку. Если вы предоставите текст ошибки + класс в котором происходит ошибка, вместо кучи слов и никому не нужных репозиториев, то помогут вам гораздо быстрее

Comment: ошибку трудно описать - не выкладывать сюда же все файлы. и описывать директории. вы серьезно предлагаете мне их все сюда выложить с скринами директорий ? казалось специалисту быстрее будет запустить у себя полную копию и за пару мин понять в чем проблема, чем не специалисту объяснить, что пошло не так

Comment: Значит плохие видео смотрите, раз не можете определить место, где происходит ошибка

Comment: понятно, попробую ваш совет применить для исправления моей проблемы с двумя маааленькими проектами. не рабочими

Comment: @Stanislav, часто по логам ошибки проблему определить можно быстрее чем запускать что-то. К тому же время прочитать лог есть у многих, а вот клонировать-зупаскать проект у очень немногих. Исходя из этого ссылку на репозиторий следует прилагать только в крайнем случае и только после максимально детального описания проблемы с максимом информации о ней. Вот вам пример моего вопроса, где ссылка на репу в самом конце, а до неё - масса информации. И проблема в итоге была в баге/фиче компилятора, что врядли ваш случай:

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1025395/angular-prod-build-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%91%d1%82-error-in-cannot-assign-to-a-reference-or-variable

Comment: Юрий , а можно вам по скайпу позвонить? просто мне не с кем посоветоваться, опыта мало, вопрос по 4-5 таблицам и связи между ними, 5 минут Вашего времени выручат меня во многих днях... я сильно запутался